# Use Group by in rails on attribute which is not in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I have a Model Event which has attribute date:DateTime

I want to group Event by only Date , If i use group_by(&:date) then it group by DateTime, I cannot change Model attribute because I need Time also to display later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Event.group_by(&:date_col)


def group_by_criteria
  date_col.to_date.to_s(:db)
end

Event.group_by(&:group_by_criteria)
```

This will group by Date only.

Comment: Can you please explain what rails does in group_by_criteria method, i didn't get (:db) .

Comment: # :db format outputs time in UTC
This link helps u more http://chris.finne.us/2011/09/23/rails-3-tosdb-when-database-time-is-not-utc/